# c# wmi invokemethod not affected windows 10

Tags: c#, wmi

i wrote this code to disable network adapter with wmi:

```
public static bool DisableAdapter(string ConnectionName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsAdapterEnabled(ConnectionName))
            {
                SelectQuery wmiQuery =
                    new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionId != NULL");
                ManagementObjectSearcher searchProcedure = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
                foreach (ManagementObject item in searchProcedure.Get())
                {
                    if (((string) item["NetConnectionId"]).Match(ConnectionName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        var ret=item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

that is fine on windows 7 but failed on windows 10 !!!!!
i checked security and the invokmethod return value is '0'

thanks.

Comment: Are you running your code in Windows 10 as Administrator? How about Windows 7?

Comment: yes. i'm administrator

Comment: Starting with Windows XP, WMI requires Administrator privileges for system queries. If you run as standard user you won't get the results you need. Make sure you are running your code as Admin by opening visual studio as admin or adding an application manifest and configuring it to request admin privileges.